# Why is this an illegal start of expression?and not a statement?

Tags: java

after using javac in CMD I get illegal start of expression error and not a statement.

```
String FirstName= "James";
String LastName= "OLiver";
//Display the message
System.out.println( "Welcome "  + "FirstName" + "LastName" + You are + age + "years Old";)
```

Comment: //variables 
           String FirstName= "James";
           String LastName= "OLiver";
                   //Display the message
System.out.println( "Welcome "  + "FirstName" + "LastName" + You are + age + "years Old";)

Comment: + "years Old";) -> compilation error.
Make use of an IDE to avoid these kind of compilation errors.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the statement is called outside of any routine, at class level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println( "Welcome "  + FirstName + LastName + "You are" + age + "years Old");
```

If you want to use the contents of your string variables do not enclose them in `""` and also put the `;` outside of the parenthesis.